# How to install standard Python module into Iron Python?

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm writing some ETL scripts in Iron Python and have found that I could benefit from using the date parser in module `dateutil`.  I know I can use my standard python library by pointing Iron Python at the appropriate location.  My scripts, however, will likely run on a machine with Iron Python but without plain vanilla Python installed.

How can I install `dateutil` (or other standard Python modules) into my Iron Python library?

I've tried simply copying the `.egg` from the standard site-packages directory to the Iron Python site-packages directory, but this results in an `ImportError` when I import `dateutil`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IronPython doesn't support eggs (because it [doesn't support zipimport](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/391)), but if you just place the folder containing the .py files in `site-packages` it should work (as long as it doesn't use a C extension).

Eggs are just zip files, so you may have to rename it to get at the .py files.